# problem with list_rows with max_results value set and to_dataframe in Kaggle's "Intro to SQL" course

Tags: python, google-bigquery, kaggle

I could use some help. In part 1, ["Getting Started with SQL and BigQuery"](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/getting-started-with-sql-and-bigquery), I'm running into the following issue. I've gotten down to In[7]:

```
# Preview the first five lines of the "full" table
client.list_rows(table, max_results=5).to_dataframe()
```

and I get the error:

```
getting_started_with_bigquery.py:41: UserWarning: Cannot use bqstorage_client if max_results is set, reverting to fetching data with the tabledata.list endpoint.
  client.list_rows(table, max_results=5).to_dataframe()
```

I'm writing my code in Notepad++ then running by calling it in the command prompt on Windows. I've gotten everything else working up until this point, but I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. A Google search leads me to the [source code for google.cloud.bigquery.table](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/table.html) which looks like that error should come up if pandas is not installed, so I installed it and I added `import pandas` to my code, but I'm still getting the same error.

Here is my full code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os 
import pandas

#need to set credential path
credential_path = (r"C:\Users\crlas\learningPython\google_application_credentials.json")
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

#create a "Client" object
client = bigquery.Client()

#construct a reference to the "hacker_news" dataset
dataset_ref = client.dataset("hacker_news", project="bigquery-public-data")
#API request - fetch the dataset 
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

#list all tables in the dataset
tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset))
#print all table names
for table in tables:
    print(table.table_id)
print()

#construct a reference to the "full" table
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("full")
#API request - fetch the dataset 
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
#print info on all the columns in the "full" table
print(table.schema)
# print("table schema should have printed above")
print()
#preview first 5 lines of the table
client.list_rows(table, max_results=5).to_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the warning message says - *UserWarning: Cannot use bqstorage_client if max_results is set, reverting to fetching data with the tabledata.list endpoint.*

So this is still working with the warning and using tabledata api to retrieve data.
You just need to point the output to a dataframe object and print it, like below:

```
df = client.list_rows(table, max_results=5).to_dataframe()
print(df)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Being fairly new to this, I don't see how you got that answer working with that warning message. Would you mind explaining to help me learn?